# How to use values from one data frame to inform a summing function within another data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have dataframe with large number of GPS points derived from animal movement data. I calculated the distance between consecutive points and stored it as a separate column. So my data looks like this:

```
< Dist
  TagID    Date        Time      location.long location.lat Distance
    FW  15.10.2018  02:12:14.000    26.8666632  41.6550714  0
    FW  15.10.2018  02:15:22.000    26.8666077  41.655001   3.7
    FW  15.10.2018  02:31:12.000    26.8666417  41.6551456  4.5
    FW  15.10.2018  02:50:47.000    26.8665424  41.6549653  2.4
    FW  15.10.2018  03:00:45.000    26.8665161  41.6549384  9.8
    FW  15.10.2018  03:05:35.000    26.8665179  41.6549765  8.8
    FW  16.10.2018  08:00:20.000    26.8664499  41.6549864  0
    FW  16.10.2018  08:05:07.000    26.8664861  41.6550659  1.1
    FW  16.10.2018  08:10:08.000    26.8665225  41.655125   7.5
    FW  16.10.2018  08:15:06.000    26.866505   41.6550936  7.5
    FW  16.10.2018  08:20:06.000    26.8664646  41.6550879  3.2
    FW  16.10.2018  08:25:07.000    26.8635185  41.6515747  6.6
    FW  16.10.2018  08:40:28.000    26.8664751  41.6550872  2.3
    FW  17.10.2018  10:10:06.000    26.8735928  41.5852645  0
    FW  17.10.2018  10:15:06.000    26.8455718  41.5654656  3.2
    FW  17.10.2018  10:20:06.000    26.7989363  41.543988   4.5
    FW  17.10.2018  10:25:06.000    26.7581078  41.5424566  3.4
    FW  17.10.2018  10:30:06.000    26.7282547  41.560534   3.1
    FW  17.10.2018  10:35:06.000    26.7184667  41.5541104  1.0
    FW  17.10.2018  10:40:06.000    26.6363721  41.549993   6.8
    FW  17.10.2018  10:45:06.000    26.6293603  41.5496727  0.5
    FW  17.10.2018  10:50:06.000    26.6293732  41.5496753  11.2
    FW  17.10.2018  10:55:06.000    26.6293623  41.5496688  7.8
    FW  17.10.2018  11:00:06.000    26.6292996  41.549678   9.4
    FW  17.10.2018  11:05:07.000    26.6293224  41.5496449  1.2
    FW  18.10.2018  08:40:06.000    26.6294363  41.5496057  0
    FW  18.10.2018  08:45:06.000    26.6294137  41.5496145  16.3
    FW  18.10.2018  08:50:06.000    26.6294167  41.5496079  12.4
    FW  18.10.2018  08:55:06.000    26.6294302  41.549607   22.0
    FW  18.10.2018  09:00:06.000    26.6294248  41.5496141  4.3
    FW  18.10.2018  09:05:06.000    26.6294258  41.549612   2.1
    FW  18.10.2018  09:10:06.000    26.6294335  41.5496148  0.6
    FW  18.10.2018  09:15:06.000    26.6294349  41.5496131  1.6
    FW  18.10.2018  09:20:06.000    26.6294279  41.5496086  11.6
    FW  18.10.2018  09:25:06.000    26.6294394  41.5496087  2.3
    FW  18.10.2018  09:30:07.000    26.6294366  41.5496005  1.8
    FW  18.10.2018  09:35:06.000    26.6294161  41.5496169  7.5
    FW  18.10.2018  09:40:06.000    26.6294205  41.5496155  12.6
    FW  18.10.2018  09:45:07.000    26.6294313  41.5496143  5.9
```

In another data frame ("Rows) i have the following information:

```
< Rows
Date    Row_number
15.10.2018  4
16.10.2018  5
17.10.2018  9
18.10.2018  12
```

The values in "Row_number" show the number of the row from the first dataframe which is of particular interest for me. **So i need to use the second data frame ("Rows") as source of information. Based on that for the "Dist" i need to calculate the sum of the values in column "Distance" from the first row up to the row number indicated in "Rows" data frame for every particular date.** So for example for 15.10.2018 i need to sum the distances up to the fourth row - 0+3.7+4.5+2.4=10.6. For 17.10.2018 sum from the first row of the day to the 9th row and so on.

So i guess i should split first the data by Dates in order to create separate units and than somehow use the sapply?

```
sp <- split(Dist, Dist$Date)
sapply(sp, function(sp){.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can join the two datasets and then grouped by 'Date', get the `sum` of 'Distance' that got subsetted based on the values of 'Row_number'

```
library(tidyverse)
left_join(Dist, Rows) %>% 
    group_by(Date) %>%
    mutate(DistanceSum = sum(Distance[seq_len(Row_number[1])], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly what i needed!

Comment: Now i tried with the bigger dataset and realised that only the first value it returns is correct. The next values are for some reason erroneous. For the example above for 15.10.2018 it correctly returns a sum of 10.6 but for 16.10.2018 the result is 20.4 but it should be 19.3 (sum from first to 5th row for that date). Any idea? Sorry for bothering

Comment: @VSta  In your description, it says that the sequence is counted from 1.

Comment: sorry for that. I meant from first point of each date. So, the idea is to sum the distances from the first point of that day to the n-th point of the same day

Comment: @VSta It is a bit difficult to test your conditions as the example showed have row number 134 and others.  Can you please change it to according to the example

Comment: Yes, now i added data for more days